# Create a developer portal/APIGEE+ WORDPRESS/

Tags: web, portal, apigee, web-development-server

There is an existing developer portal in Drupal that uses APIGEE to give 3rd party developers access to remote API and documentation. The  portal is not configured and costumized correctly so for this reason the portal has many problems.The website has its own database but also uses APigee db. 
My task is to create a website by using cms/probably will be wordpress/, migrate the users and the forum from the existing database and establish connection with the API provider. 
The idea is not to use the dev portal provided by APIGEE and DRUPAL but just make my own and use some of the things provided by Apigee.

Could tou give me some directions is that possible and where I need to dive in more?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the developer management and key management features in Apigee is accessible using REST APIs (protected by role based access control aka RBAC)

You can always develop any portal or UI of your choice and invoke these APIs provided by Apigee to implement features such as

- Creating a new developer
- allowing the developer to subscribe to API products
- allow the developer create and manage his own API Apps, Keys
- allow the developer to view App analytics etc.

You can follow the API documentation here: 
https://docs.apigee.com/api/apps-developer

Comment: Thank you! I already achive that. It was easier than I expected.